# Запись Json в PHP

Tags: php, json

Есть таблица, из которой данные представляются в таком виде (рис. 1)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вопрос. Как представить эти данные в JSON с помощью PHP

```
[{"Барнаул":["282552.45","347417.89","446495.40"],"Итого по компании":["18320150.14","25944728.83","32853227.43"], и т.д....}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Желательно указывать в вопросе в каком виде вы получаете данные из БД, но если предположить, что они представлены в виде простого массива, то ваша задача решается так:

```php
$data = [
    ['name' => 'Интернет магазин', 'value' => 1146403.98],
    ['name' => 'Интернет магазин', 'value' => 1266412.98],
    ['name' => 'Интернет магазин', 'value' => 1487791.98],
    //..
];

$result = [];
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $result[$row['name']][] = $row['value'];
}

var_dump(json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));
```

По поводу флага во втором аргументе `json_encode()` читайте [здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/json.constants.php).

Comment: Спасибо! Очень помогли:)